# how do i get json data into php variables that have @attribute in them

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have always struggled with fetching arrays from apis. Not sure why i cant wrap my headaround them.

This time around, i cant seem to access keys and results.

Im using curl to fetch the json array results. However i cant seem to access them properly. I keep getting php errors Warning: Illegal string offset. obviously im not accessing the correct keys.

I tried to decode and encode and access them that way to no avail.

I have read through tons of questions on here and other places and just cant get it to work.

the code i have is:

```
<?php
$url="http://localhost/geeks/monitor/xml.php?plugin=complete&jsonp&callback=getData";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$resultjson=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

$array = json_decode(json_encode($resultjson), true);
print_r($array);
?>
```

It returns the following:

```
getData({"Generation":{"@attributes":{"version":"3.2.x","timestamp":"1446194411"}},"Options":{"@attributes":{"tempFormat":"c","byteFormat":"auto_binary","refresh":"60000","threshold":"90","showPickListTemplate":"true","showPickListLang":"true","showCPUListExpanded":"true","showCPUInfoExpanded":"false"}},"Vitals":{"@attributes":{"Hostname":"domain.domain.com","IPAddr":"127.1.1.1","Kernel":"2.6.18-404.el5 (SMP) x86_64","Distro":"CentOS release 5.11 (Final)","Distroicon":"CentOS.png","Uptime":"778721.78","Users":"0","LoadAvg":"0.82 0.83 0.81","SysLang":"English United States (en_US)","CodePage":"UTF-8","Processes":"616","ProcessesRunning":"3","ProcessesSleeping":"611","ProcessesZombie":"2","OS":"Linux"}},"Network":{"NetDevice":[{"@attributes":{"Name":"lo","RxBytes":"20523255371","TxBytes":"20523255371","Err":"0","Drops":"0","Info":"127.0.0.1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"eth0","RxBytes":"32510645609","TxBytes":"337131806000","Err":"0","Drops":"0","Info":"00-0C-29-7A-BB-86;202.130.34.3"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"eth1","RxBytes":"4076707540","TxBytes":"278070","Err":"0","Drops":"0","Info":"00-0C-29-7A-BB-90"}}]},"Hardware":{"@attributes":{"Name":"VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform\/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07\/30\/2013"},"PCI":{"Device":[{"@attributes":{"Name":"Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX\/ZX\/DX - 82443BX\/ZX\/DX Host bridge","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX\/ZX\/DX - 82443BX\/ZX\/DX AGP bridge","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB\/EB\/MB PIIX4 ISA","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB\/EB\/MB PIIX4 IDE","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB\/EB\/MB PIIX4 ACPI","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic \/ Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port","Count":"32"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller","Count":"1"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Ethernet controller: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller","Count":"1"}}]},"IDE":{"Device":{"@attributes":{"Name":"hdc: VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive","Count":"1"}}},"SCSI":{"Device":{"@attributes":{"Name":"VMware Virtual disk (Direct-Access)","Count":"1"}}},"CPU":{"CpuCore":[{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}},{"@attributes":{"Model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz","CpuSpeed":"2100.000","Cache":"15728640","Bogomips":"4200.00"}}]}},"Memory":{"@attributes":{"Free":"60383232","Used":"15709798400","Total":"15770181632","Percent":"100"},"Details":{"@attributes":{"App":"4206075904","AppPercent":"27","Buffers":"864247808","BuffersPercent":"6","Cached":"10639474688","CachedPercent":"67"}},"Swap":{"@attributes":{"Free":"6190227456","Used":"50888704","Total":"6241116160","Percent":"1"},"Mount":{"@attributes":{"MountPointID":"1","FSType":"","Name":"SWAP","Free":"6190227456","Used":"50888704","Total":"6241116160","Percent":"1","MountPoint":"\/dev\/mapper\/VolGroup00-LogVol01"}}}},"FileSystem":{"Mount":[{"@attributes":{"MountPointID":"1","FSType":"ext3","Name":"\/dev\/mapper\/VolGroup00-LogVol00","Free":"77318148096","Used":"666516889600","Total":"784311173120","Percent":"85","MountOptions":"rw, usrjquota=quota.user, jqfmt=vfsv0","Inodes":"3","MountPoint":"\/"}},{"@attributes":{"MountPointID":"2","FSType":"ext3","Name":"\/dev\/sda1","Free":"70255616","Used":"27912192","Total":"103512064","Percent":"27","MountOptions":"rw","Inodes":"1","MountPoint":"\/boot"}},{"@attributes":{"MountPointID":"3","FSType":"tmpfs","Name":"tmpfs","Free":"7885090816","Used":"0","Total":"7885090816","Percent":"0","MountOptions":"rw","Inodes":"1","MountPoint":"\/dev\/shm"}}]},"MBInfo":{},"UPSInfo":{},"Plugins":{},"Errors":{}})
```

As you can see, it doesnt print "friendly". So if someone knows the best way to make that print more human readable that would be great too. However still not the issue.

So how can i access each of them and put each into php variables.

I have tried so many different ways and i am obviously not selecting the keys correctly.

Comment: would your desired result be a two dimensional array? because that's what the data is coming out as

Comment: print_r(json_encode($resultjson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

Comment: i tried that already. I end up with exactly the same messy return. not human readable so to speak.

Comment: hmm try print("<pre>" . print_r($array, true) . "</pre>");

Comment: tried that earlier too. Tried it again just to be sure.
It all prints out on 1 line and gives scroll bars to the web browser. So strange... I wonder if its because im using curl?

Comment: Use that but change your $array to $array = json_decode($resultjson,true)

Comment: prints nothing at all. what the hell is going on.   :(

Comment: dang. wish I could help more. If you also have it loaded, or can load it on a iive server I can take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93783/discussion-between-elgoots-and-ambe5960).

Comment: i ended up getting it. i posted the answer. Thank you for your help anyway. Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoo! Ended up getting it. Started from scratch and changed to file_get_contents.

I then grabbed it and declared utf8 and removed the crap from it.

then i made sure i declared json_decode true so it would be in an array properly.

Now i can access what i need easily. Below is my final code listing all as an array and also an example of accessing only what i needed (version):

```
<?php
$url="http://localhost/monitor/xml.php?plugin=complete&json&callback=getData";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$json = preg_replace('/,\s*([\]}])/m', '$1', utf8_encode($html));

$json = json_decode($json, true);

echo '<p>Version : '.$json['Generation']['@attributes']['version'].'';

print_r($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your json like this :

```
$array['Generation']['@attributes']['version']
```

*o/p => 3.2.x* 
You can read your json in proper way at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i ended up getting it. i posted the answer. Thank you for your help anyway. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

json_decode($json, true);

```
Array
(
    [Generation] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [version] => 3.2.x
                    [timestamp] => 1446194411
                )

        )
```

echo attr

```
  echo $array["Generation"]["@attributes"]["timestamp"];
```

Comment: nothing at all. no errors, no content:

$array = json_decode($resultjson, true);

echo $array["Generation"]["@attributes"]["timestamp"];

Comment: i ended up getting it. i posted the answer. Thank you for your help anyway. Appreciated